# Should a radiation-filled Universe be scale invariant?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

Imagine a spatially flat Universe, without cosmological constant, filled only with EM radiation.

As Maxwell's equations without charges or currents are scale invariant then should this Universe be scale invariant as a whole? i.e. should there be no length scale associated with such a Universe?

Friedmann's equation for such a Universe is conventionally given by:
$$\left(\frac{\dot a}{a}\right)^2 \propto \frac{1}{a^4}$$
The solution is:
$$a(t) = \frac{t^{1/2}}{t_0^{1/2}}$$
where $t_0$ is the current age of the Universe.

Now let us calculate the particle horizon distance $D$ given by:
$$D = \int_0^{t_0} \frac{dt}{a(t)}$$
We find that:
$$D = 2 t_0$$

Therefore conventional theory says there is a length scale associated with this Universe.

But is that reasonable?

PS If for some reason we had $\rho \propto 1/a^2$ so that $a(t) = t/t_0$ then we could have a truly scale invariant cosmology where both the particle horizon and the cosmological event horizon diverge leaving no length scale.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of my reasoning here, but if the universe is filled with radiation then doesn't that radiation have to have a particular temperature? If so then the Planck formula gives it a characteristic wavelength, which breaks the scale symmetry. I don't know but I would assume the Friedmann equation is based on radiation at equilibrium at some temperature (which is constant over space but not time for an expanding universe).

Comment: @Nathaniel there does not have to be a specific temperature. There could easily be a radiation profile that does not fit to a blackbody curve at all and thus would not have a definable temperature.

Comment: @John $1/a^2$ is the proportionality for the curvature energy density. Furthermore, Maxwell's equations are scale invariant but that has no bearing on equations describing the geometry of spacetime. A universe with only radiation still has spacetime and radiation warps spacetime. There is no reason to assume that scale invariance of Maxwell's equations implies scale invariance of, say, the particle horizon or the metric. If there is a speed of light and you define a finite age for the universe, then there must be a relevant particle horizon.

Comment: Related [comments](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/19466/why-is-the-cmb-nearly-scale-invariant?show=19758#a19758) about why the CMB is theoretically expected to be scale invariant